Adding Messenger customer chat feature on react app
I have recently tried integrating messenger chat feature on my react vite app with page id and app id and tried deploy it and add the url in the page too but it is giving cors error.
here is the code:
import { CustomChat, FacebookProvider } from 'react-facebook';
const FacebookChat = () => {
return (





);
};
export default FacebookChat;

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
